# instalar dotnet core en OL7.6

Tags: linux, .net-core

estoy tratando de instalar dotnet core 2.2, en Oracle Linux 7.6.
estaba revisando la documentacion oficial https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install  y me doy cuenta que no existe en la lista de sistemas operativos linux una version expecifica para esta version.
Alguien ha tenido la necesidad de instalar en este sist operativo en particular? que otra distribucion de linux seria similar?
sorry si es muy basico lo que pregunto, estoy un poco perdido en este tema.
Saludos y gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

luego de publicar mi pregunta, buscando un poco mas en las diferencias entre RHEL y OL, aparecio la respuesta, la cual es Centos.. asi que segui el tutorial para centos, y despues de un par de errores en los repositorios, por fin pude instalar dotnet en OL7.6
saludos

Comment: Buenas! o podrías usar Docker.... Si es un server donde corre la app, puedes Dockenizar la app que no es nada complicado y correrla desde ahí. SI es para desarrollo, esta bien como hiciste

Comment: gracias por el dato de docker, aun no me he metido a profundizar en ese tema, pero se ve bastante potente y facil. Saludos